# How are wallet passwords stored?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, encryption

How are wallet passwords stored on the user's machine, and what encryption / hashes are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wallet passwords are never stored on your computer. They're used at the time of input to derive the encryption key which is then used to decrypt your actual wallet data.

Deriving the key from the password is done with CryptoNight. The encryption of wallet data (using the derived key) is done with [ChaCha8](http://cr.yp.to/chacha/chacha-20080128.pdf).

More details can be found [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1629/what-encryption-algorithm-is-used-for-the-wallet-keys-file).