# data stored in the wallet cache

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, security

According to the Wolfram Warptangent, [Point Release 1 notes](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases/tag/v0.10.1), there is now an `expansion of the data stored in the wallet cache, including the GUI address book`

Is the new data being stored there secured the same way as wallet cache data was stored before? Besides the GUI address book example, what additional data will now be stored in the wallet cache?

Comment: Wallet cache is encrypted with your wallet password so you can safely store whatever you want in it. Could you clarify what you're asking here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the new data being stored there secured the same way as wallet
>   cache data was stored before?

Yes, all the stored data is encrypted using the wallet password. For details on the encryption scheme, see [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1629/what-encryption-algorithm-is-used-for-the-wallet-keys-file).

> Besides the GUI address book example, what additional data will now be
>   stored in the wallet cache?

Anything you can think of that needs secure & private persistent storage on the user end. For example (not necessarily newly added): record of outputs belonging to the wallet, record of signed key images for each output and their spent status, custom transaction notes, transaction keys, address book records, etc.

See also: [*What data do the wallet files contain?*](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2803/what-data-do-the-wallet-files-contain)

Comment: Default settings aren't in the cache, they're in the keys file.

Comment: Corrected. Are we saving some GUI settings somewhere, like window positions, last entered address, sort order for tx history?

Comment: ~/.config/monero-project for GUI settings. Your window manager might also save window geometry etc.