# Monerujo Send Pword Reset?

Tags: wallet-recovery, monerujo

I can log into Monerujo just fine. I have no idea what my "Give" password is. I can access this wallet because i have fingerprint auth turned on. Is there anyway i can transfer funds from this wallet without knowing the password although i can login via fingerprint?

Comment: Monerujo uses the very same wallet files the **monero-wallet-cli** uses. The **Android File Transfer** application allows wallet files to be transferred to or from Android devices to a computer supporting **monero-wallet-cli**. I have no idea if or how fingerprint auth is currently used by Monerujo.

Comment: @skaht Should this be turned into an answer?

Comment: Did you wrote the 25 mnemonic words displayed during the creation of the wallet?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the EXACT same issue.

Comment: @user10431 - could you perhaps open a new thread on r/monerosupport (Reddit)?

Answer (score 1):

Typical passwords specified by endusers are used by **Monerujo** to unlock native **monero-wallet-cli** [**chacha8**](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1629/what-encryption-algorithm-is-used-for-the-wallet-keys-file) encrypted files. I've not examined Monerujo **CrAzYpass** functionality that might be integrated with 2 factor authentication such as fingerprints. Unclear if CrAzYpass-enabled password files are portable to other devices.

Monerujo can use the very same wallet files the **monero-wallet-cli** uses. The [**Android File Transfer**](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/) application allows wallet files to be transferred to or from Android devices to an external host supporting monero-wallet-cli.

Beside enabling an end user to specify a server name and port number, the Monerujo application allows an enhanced **username:password@server_adddress:port** syntax to be applid when connecting to a **monerod** server.  Both the **monero-wallet-cli** and iOS **Cake Wallet** clients also support this same functionality for establishing server connections. However, I do prefer not having to drill down so many levels in the Cake Wallet to specify a specific server.

**Related Command Line Interface Information:**

1. Server Syntax:  **monerod --confirm-external-bind --rpc-bind-ip**  *address* **--rpc-bind-port** *port* **--rpc-login** *username:password*

`% monerod --confirm-external-bind --rpc-bind-ip 192.168.200.100 --rpc-bind-port 18081 --rpc-login test:123`

2. Client Syntax: **monero-wallet-cli --daemon-address** *address:port* **--daemon-login** *username:password*

`% monero-wallet-cli --daemon-address 192.168.200.100:18081 --daemon-login test:123`

Comment: THIS DOES NOT ANSWER THE QUESTION!